# How to obtain CoNLL 2011/2012 format with StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like to run CoreNLP and get the output
formatted in the CoNLL 2011/2012 format.  Is there a straightforward way to get
CoNLL output? Or where would I have to poke around in the code to make
this happen? CoreNLP can read/write CoNLL format since dcoref participated in the 2011 Shared Task)?

Answer (score 1):

See the instructions for using the `SieveCoreferenceSystem` on [this page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml). CoNLL 2011/2012 file reading and writing isn't incorporated into the main Stanford CoreNLP class, but this class can run a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline on CoNLL 2011/2012 format data.